# exit script called from within a menu without exiting the menu

Tags: menu

I have written this menu that calls forth several scripts. One of this script is

```
dbus-monitor --system
```

so it displays live traffic over dbus.

but when I want to exit this I normally do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, but that also exits my menu and I would like to just return to my menu.

is there a code that I can put after the dbus-moniter, when an exit is detected it starts my menu again?
my menu is just another .sh script

or ....

---------------- clarify ---------------

i am not that advanced "yet" ;) in scripting. this is the menu where i call my dbus script

```
select opt in "dbus Live Traffic" "option 2" "Main menu" "Quit"
    do
        case $opt in
            "dbus Live Traffic")
                curl -s -u lalala:hihihi ftp://ftp.somewhere.com/folder/dbuslivetraffic.sh | bash ;;   
            "option 2")
                do_something ;;   
            "Main menu")
                main_menu;;
            "Quit")
                quit_menu;;
        esac
        if [[ $opt != "Main menu" ]] || [[ $opt != "Quit" ]] ;
        then
            main_menu
        fi
    done
```

and this is the content of my dbuslivetraffic.sh

```
dbus-monitor --system
```

for now just this single line, but maybe in the near future more code will be added to this script.

i don't really understand where i need to put the `TRAP` function like suggested by @RoVo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run the command in a subshell and `trap` on `SIGINT` running `kill 0` to kill the process group of the subshell only.

```
select opt in a b; do
    case $REPLY in
      1)
        (
          trap "kill -SIGINT 0" SIGINT
          sleep 10
        )
        ;;
      2)
        sleep 10
        ;;
    esac
done
```

- Selecting (1) will let you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> without killing the menu.
- Selecting (2) and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> will kill the menu, too.

Answer (score 4):

### Graphical desktop environment

You can run the command in another terminal window (if you have a graphical desktop environment).

The following shellscript uses `xterm`, which can be installed with

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xterm
```

but you can use other terminal window emulators too, for example `gnome-terminal` or `lxterminal`.

Shellscript:

```
#!/bin/bash

select opt in "dbus-monitor --system" htop exit; do
    case $REPLY in
      1)
        xterm -e dbus-monitor --system 2>/dev/null
        ;;
      2)
        htop
        ;;
      3)
        exit
        ;;
    esac
done
```

### Text screen (this method works also in a graphical desktop)

You can use the trap method in @RoVo's answer.

The important thing is to run the `trap` command *before* you run the command, that you must interrupt with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

- So if you want it in the whole menu script, put it in the beginning.
- If you want it only when it is absolutely necessary, run a subshell and put the `trap` command inside the subshell as illustrated by @RoVo, alternatively with

  ```
  bash -c 'trap "kill -SIGINT 0" SIGINT; dbus-monitor --system';;
  ```

Shellscript:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Press the Enter key to print out the menu again"

trap "kill -SIGINT 0" SIGINT

select opt in "dbus-monitor --system" "option 2" "Quit"
do
    case $opt in
        "dbus-monitor --system")
            dbus-monitor --system;;   
        "option 2")
            echo "Hello World";;   
        "Quit")
            exit;;
    esac
done
```

**Comment**

Your `curl` command line did not work for me, so I invoke my local `dbus-monitor` to test that the shellscript works when using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

Comment: i dont have a graphical desktop environment. and i cant install other shells so i am limited in my actions

Comment: @WingZero, in that case you cannot use the method in this answer. Is RoVo's method with a trap working for you?

Comment: hey, i just update my initial question, because the comment section was to small

Comment: problem is i am a novice in shell scripting, so i don't know where the trap method from @RoVo needs to fit in

Comment: @WingZero, I added an alternative with the trap method to my answer. Try that shellscript and edit it to make it do what you want.

Comment: I tried to put the trap in front, too, and it will successfully kill the spawned processes, but you can not kill the menu anymore with `ctrl-c`.

Comment: @RoVo, That's right.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @pLumo's [excellent answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/490278/220260), you may define a function like this, to shorten the amount of code needed in each `case`:

```
run_in_subshell () {
    command="$@"
    (
        trap "kill -INT 0" INT
        $command
    )
}
```

Then in the `case`:

```
select opt in a b; do
    case $REPLY in
      1) run_in_subshell sleep 10 ;;
      2) sleep 10 ;;
    esac
done
```